# Clustering number pairs

Tags: sorting

I have a set of number pairs in random order in an array as follows:

(5,6) (2,7) (3,7) (1,2) (3,4) (4,5)

I need to link all these numbers based on the common number when comparing pairs. So my expected output would be: 1,2,7,3,4,5,6. I can easily get it if pairs can be ordered in the   sequence of (1,2) (2,7) (3,7) (3,4) (4,5) (5,6). Any algorithm that support this sorting?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Using Java programming language

Comment: This is one of the algorithms found but it is not clear to me. 1) Create an array of int, as long as the number of points.  
2) Initialize each array element to its own index.  
3) Sort the pairs by their lower-numbered member, secondarily by their higher member, in ascending order  
3) For each pair, in sorted order  
    a) choose the lower point number  
    b) read the value at that array index  
    c) set the value at the higher array index to that value.